# Motivation and intuition behind concept of totally bounded-ness in metric spaces

Tags: metric-spaces, compactness

The way I understand it is, a set in a m.s. is totally bounded means the set Admits a finite open cover of fixed size.
Regardless of whether it admits an arbitrary open cover.

Why do we need totally bounded-ness? And why should the sizes of open sets be fixed?